# pass a string to function model in fable package

Tags: r

I can easily do

```
require(fable)
require(tsibble)
require(tsibbledata) 
tourism %>% model(avg = MEAN(Trips))
```

and it clearly works.

Instead I would like to achieve something like:

```
require(rlang)
tourism %>% model(parse_expr('avg = MEAN(Trips)'))
```

but I get:

```
Error: Model definition(s) incorrectly created: parse_expr("MEAN(Trips)")
Check that specified model(s) are model definitions.
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

We need to `eval`uate

```
tourism %>%
      model(avg = eval(rlang::parse_expr('avg = MEAN(Trips)')))
```

-output

```
# A mable: 304 x 4
# Key:     Region, State, Purpose [304]
   Region         State              Purpose      avg
   <chr>          <chr>              <chr>    <model>
 1 Adelaide       South Australia    Business  <MEAN>
 2 Adelaide       South Australia    Holiday   <MEAN>
 3 Adelaide       South Australia    Other     <MEAN>
 4 Adelaide       South Australia    Visiting  <MEAN>
 5 Adelaide Hills South Australia    Business  <MEAN>
 6 Adelaide Hills South Australia    Holiday   <MEAN>
 7 Adelaide Hills South Australia    Other     <MEAN>
 8 Adelaide Hills South Australia    Visiting  <MEAN>
 9 Alice Springs  Northern Territory Business  <MEAN>
10 Alice Springs  Northern Territory Holiday   <MEAN>
# … with 294 more rows
```

Comment: Do you know how to adapt this for passing regressors? The above code fails on my end if I try something like `tourism %>% model(avg = eval(rlang::parse_expr("MEAN(Trips ~ season('A'))"))`

Comment: @JoeBringley It is possible.  Have a great day!